# $\mathbb{E}(\log(X_{max}/X_{min}) )$ of Weibull(alpha, 1)

Tags: expected-value, weibull-distribution

I'm trying to find the expectation of log(max/min) from n samples of Weibull(alpha, 1).

But I keep failing. Can anybody give some hints?

I **tried**:

$\mathbb{E}(\log(X_{max}/X_{min}) ) = \int_0^{\infty} P(\log(X_{max}/X_{min}) > y)dy $

Comment: Looks like this needs the `self-study` tag.

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: @wolfies Because presumably OP is 'self-studying'. Whatever that means here.

Comment: By that broad defn, all questions on Stack exchange would be self-study, and the tag would have no purpose. My understanding is that the tag 'self-study' is a euphemism for doing homework, and this is not a homework problem, unless one again takes a very broad definition of that term, and the OP is presently at home while working on it ;)

Comment: @wolfies You are right. Maybe I need to get better at identifying 'self-study' questions. It's just that I had tagged a lot of my own posts with that tag and none of them were my 'homework' or some kind of assignment to be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Simplifying the problem:** The [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) with unit shape is the [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), so your specified sampling mechanism is equivalent to $X_1, ..., X_n \sim \text{IID Exp}(\text{Scale} = \alpha)$.  For all arguments $x \geqslant 0$ you have the density and distribution functions:

$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\alpha} \cdot \exp \Big( - \frac{x}{\alpha} \Big) \quad \quad \quad \quad F_X(x) = 1-\exp \Big( - \frac{x}{\alpha} \Big) .$$

Now, write the order statistics in standard notation as $X_{(1)} \leqslant \cdots \leqslant X_{(n)}$.  Since the logarithmic transformation is an increasing function, the order of the original $X$ values is preserved under the transformation.  Hence, using the properties of the logarithm, and the linearity property of the expectation operator, you have:

$$\mathbb{E}(\ln (X_{\max}/X_{\min})) = \mathbb{E}(\ln X_{(n)} - \ln X_{(1)}) = \mathbb{E}(\ln X_{(n)}) - \mathbb{E}(\ln X_{(1)}).$$

This means that your problem reduces to one of finding the moments of transformed order statistics.  This can be solved using standard methods for dealing with order statistics.

---

**Finding the distribution of the order statistics:** Using [standard formulae for the distribution of the order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Probability_distributions_of_order_statistics) we have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
f_{X_{(1)}}(x) 
&= n (1-F_X(x))^{n-1} f_X(x) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{n}{\alpha} \cdot \exp \Big( - \frac{nx}{\alpha} \Big), \\[10pt]
f_{X_{(n)}}(x) 
&= n F_X(x)^{n-1} f_X(x) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{n}{\alpha} \cdot \exp \Big( - \frac{x}{\alpha} \Big) \Big( 1 - \exp \Big( - \frac{x}{\alpha} \Big) \Big)^{n-1} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{n}{\alpha} \cdot \exp \Big( - \frac{x}{\alpha} \Big) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose k} (-1)^k \exp \Big( - \frac{kx}{\alpha} \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{n}{\alpha} \sum_{k=1}^{n} {n-1 \choose k-1} (-1)^{k-1} \exp \Big( - \frac{kx}{\alpha} \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} {n \choose k} (-1)^{k-1} \cdot \frac{k}{\alpha} \cdot \exp \Big( - \frac{kx}{\alpha} \Big).
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

---

**Finding the moments:** Using the change of variable $r = nx/\alpha$ we have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(\ln X_{(1)}) 
&= \int \limits_0^\infty \ln(x) f_{X_{(1)}}(x) dx \\[6pt]
&= \frac{n}{\alpha} \int \limits_0^\infty \ln(x) \exp \Big( - \frac{nx}{\alpha} \Big) dx \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_0^\infty \ln \Big( \frac{\alpha r}{n} \Big) \exp (-r) dr \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_0^\infty \ln (r) \exp (-r) dr - \ln \Big( \frac{n}{\alpha} \Big) \int \limits_0^\infty \exp (-r) dr \\[6pt]
&= - \gamma + \ln \alpha - \ln n, \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Integrals).  Applying this same integral result we then have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(\ln X_{(n)}) 
&= \int \limits_0^\infty \ln(x) f_{X_{(n)}}(x) dx \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} {n \choose k} (-1)^{k-1} \cdot \frac{k}{\alpha} \int \limits_0^\infty \ln(x) \exp \Big( - \frac{kx}{\alpha} \Big) dx \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} {n \choose k} (-1)^{k-1} \Big[ -\gamma + \ln \alpha - \ln k \Big] \\[6pt]
&= (-\gamma + \ln \alpha) \sum_{k=1}^{n} {n \choose k} (-1)^{k-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} {n \choose k} (-1)^{k-1} \ln k \\[6pt]
&= (-\gamma + \ln \alpha) \times 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} {n \choose k} (-1)^k \ln k \\[6pt]
&= -\gamma + \ln \alpha + \sum_{k=1}^{n} {n \choose k} (-1)^k \ln k. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Putting this together we obtain the function:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
E(n) &\equiv \mathbb{E}(\ln (X_{\max}/X_{\min}))  \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(\ln X_{(n)}) - \mathbb{E}(\ln X_{(1)}) \\[6pt]
&= \ln n + \sum_{k=1}^{n} {n \choose k} (-1)^k \ln k \\[6pt]
&= {n \choose 2} \ln 2 - {n \choose 3} \ln 3 + {n \choose 4} \ln 4 - \cdots + (-1)^n \ln n + \ln n. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

This is a finite sum that can be easily evaluated for a given value of $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  There does not appear to be any simpler form for this expression.  It is interesting to note that this function does not depend on the scale parameter $\alpha$, so this parameter has no effect on the expected value of the log-ratio of the maximum-to-minimum value.  This is unsurprising, in view of the fact that the log-ratio of those values is invariant to changes in scale.

---

**Plotting the function in R:** This expected value function can be plotted for different input values of $n$ to get a visual sense of how the number of data points in the sample affects the expected log-ratio of the maximum-to-minimum value.  To plot the function we use the following `R` code:

```
#Create function to calculate expected value

EXP <- function(n) { if(n%%1 != 0)   { stop("Error: Input is not a positive integer") }
                 else if(n < 1)  { stop("Error: Input is not a positive integer") }
                 else if(n == 1) { 0 }
                 else            { log(n) + sum(choose(n,2:n)*(-1)^(2:n)*log(2:n)) } };


#Plot expected value function

N      <- 20;
NNN    <- (1:N);
EEE    <- rep(0, N);  for(n in 1:N) { EEE[n] <- EXP(n) };
DATA   <- data.frame(n = NNN, Expectation = EEE);
SPLINE <- as.data.frame(spline(NNN, EEE));

library(ggplot2);
ggplot(data = DATA, aes(x = n, y = Expectation)) +
  geom_point(colour = "DarkBlue") +
  geom_line(data = SPLINE, aes(x = x, y = y), colour = "Blue") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Number of Data Points", labels = (1:N), breaks = (1:N)) +
  ggtitle("Expected value of log-ratio of maximum-to-minimum") +
  labs(subtitle = "(Data from an exponential distribution)") +
  xlab("Number of Data Points") + ylab("Expected Value");
```

This generates the following plot of the function:

[image]

Comment: I think there is a small typo in $E[\log[X_{(1)}]$ .........where $\gamma + \ln(\alpha) - \ln(n)$ should be $-\gamma + \ln(\alpha) - \ln(n)$

Comment: @wolfies: Nicely spotted - I have edited to fix that error (overall answer remains the same).